# Nginx Mess (URL Redirects)

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm looking to redirect old urls to the new urls / new links. It's proving to be a mess to do just that. I'm using nginx 1.19.6 and ubuntu 18.04

I want to setup my redirects so https://ikhnetworks.com/feeds/Live/* would redirect to https://ikhnetworks.com/feeds/HD1/

https://ikhnetworks.com/Stations/* -> redirect to the respective call letters - for example
https://ikhnetworks.com/Stations/Radio/WDJO/ > https://ikhnetworks.com/WDJO/

Comment: Take a look https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I can provide you the solution as:

```
server{
  listen 443;
  server_name ikhnetworks.com;
   ...
   ...
  root /var/www/html;
  location /feeds/Live {
    return 301 https://ikhnetworks.com/feeds/HD1/;
  }
}
```